# mongoose best-practice with data layer in node application

Tags: node.js, data-access-layer, mongoose

looking into the nodejs server stack with nodejs/express and mongoose

What is considered a best practice solution?
(1) Creating a mongoose datamodel module then working with the model objects
(2) Creating a wrapper datalayer module that will internally use the mongoose model

**Pros for (1)**
I really like the OOP style classes mongoose gives me, add my own methods, my own setters and getters, I can add validation and event-handlers, and use the DataModel without redefining it in another module.

**Pros for (2)**
I should be able to mockup the data layer with simpler implementation (tests, etc..)
or switch a database if needed.

What do you think?

Comment: Thanks for this question, I feel like there's a derth of discussion around how to use Mongoose outside of a toy demo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually start with the easiest and least complex option to start and only move to a more complex one when it's really needed.  So in this case I always start with Option 1 and have yet to find an instance where I wish I had started with Option 2. If I really need to change databases, I'll do the work then instead of doing more work upfront for something I may never need.

Keep in mind that this depends on how big of a project it is and how many people are working on it.  If it's a small team (or just you) extra layers of abstraction generally aren't needed. If it's a large project with a large team, I'd take a bit longer figuring out the best architecture for long term maintainability.